# Firebase base de datos - Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para un inventario de prestamos de articulos (teclados, mouse ...) pido Carrera, nombre a quien presto, articulo, fecha, recibido en caso de que devuelvan y estado (Prestado o entregado), ok me ayude de un video para hacer la base de datos con FIREBASE.

La autenticacion funciona de maravilla pero lo que mas me interesa es la base de datos. La aplicación cuando le doy un registro me dice "Registro exitoso" pero no guarda nada.

Agradeceria mucha la ayuda, por favor.

**(variables varias declaradas)**

```
private DatabaseReference Clases;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prestamo);

    Clases = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Clases");

    Estudiante = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtEstd);
    Articulo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtArt);
    Recibido = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtRecibido);
    Fecha = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtFecha);
    Estado = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnEstado);
    btRegistrarP = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btRegistroP);
    ayuda = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnAyuda);


}
public void RegistrarPrestamo(){
    String estud = Estudiante.getText().toString();
    String artic = Articulo.getText().toString();
    String fech = Fecha .getText().toString();
    String estado = Estado.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String recib = Recibido.getText().toString();

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(estud)){
        String id = Clases.push().getKey();
        Clases lai= new Clases(id,estud, artic,fech,estado,recib);
        Clases.child(id).setValue(lai);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Registro exitoso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Introduzca un Estudiante", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
public void Ayuda(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "LLene este cuadrante en caso de estar recibiendo un Artículo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btRegistroP:
            RegistrarPrestamo();
            break;

        case R.id.btnAyuda:
            Ayuda();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La referencia esta bien y el codigo de escritura e inisializacion de la referencia esta bien.

Puede ser por dos cosas

- No habilitaste el permiso de internet en tu Manifest

  ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  ```
- Tienes tus reglas de Firebase para solo escritura de usuarios autenticados

Por otra parte, en terminos de diseño, te aconsejaria que uses nombre de variables en minusculas y no en mayusculas, puedes confundirlas con una clase u objeto

```
private DatabaseReference clasesRef;
```

Como veo que tambien tienes una instancia de `Clases`, puede que el problema este en que `Clases` esta declarado como `DatabaseReference`, y `Clases` como `Clases`, te sugiero cambiar el nombre de tu `DatabaseReference` a minusculas como propongo arriba

Answer (score 0):

Primero  obtenga la referencia de base de datos principal

```
private DatabaseReference Clases;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Clases = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
}

public void RegistrarPrestamo(){
    String id = Clases.child("Clases").push().getKey();
    Clases lai= new Clases(id,estud, artic,fech,estado,recib);
    Clases.child("Clases").child(id).setValue(lai);
}
```

[Firebase Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)